# Should I make my local reused data global in webservice in c++?

Tags: c++, global-variables

I know this question has been answered many times and globals are bad but I have a variation. I have lots of regular expressions and I create local variables of those. Also, I have lost of strings which are constant in nature. This code is part of C++ web service. Thus this objects are getting created and destroyed all the time. Thus, I wonder if I should put them in as global inside a namespace so that I can still use them without polluting the namespace.

Comment: _"global inside a namespace"_ That's a contradiction.

Comment: Oops. I meant inside a namespace but not enclosed in a function.

Comment: Please someone close it as the question which has the answer did not come up in suggestion.

Comment: @Sh​​​​​​​​​​​​iv: What's "it"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The question.

Comment: Next time consider searching instead of just relying on suggestions being shoved in your face :)

Answer (score 1):

You might have your terminology mixed up.

By definition, variables which are in a namespace are not global. When people say *"It's bad to have variables/functions/etc. defined globally"*, their express solution to that issue is usually to put those things in a namespace.

Comment: Well, not really. Often the concern is about encapsulation and testability, to which the solution is to make the constants class members.